# How to lock instantiation by a condition in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, null, instantiation

I have the next construct:

```
public Dato (String nombre, float limiteInferior, float limiteSuperior) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.limiteInferior = limiteInferior;
        this.limiteSuperior = limiteSuperior;
    }
```

I want to stop instantiation or "return null" when limiteInferior >= limiteSuperior. Something like:

```
public Dato(String nombre, float limiteInferior, float limiteSuperior) {
        //Validar que el limite superior no sea menor o igual al inferior
        if (limiteInferior < limiteSuperior) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.limiteInferior = limiteInferior;
            this.limiteSuperior = limiteSuperior;
        } else {
            this = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this in the constructor, but rather you probably want to use a factory method for this.

Comment: Have a look at the [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think you're right. But, is there another way to lock? Maybe an Exception.

Comment: @BackSlash thanks, I have a book about patterns.

Comment: @janos has good suggestions, 1+

Comment: @Human Yes, the answer by janos in this specific case shows the appropriate approach. In _this specific case_ raising an  `IllegalArgumentException` is the right choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options.

You can make the constructor `private`,
and control creating instances using a factory method, for example:

```
// not accessible from outside
private Dato(String nombre, float limiteInferior, float limiteSuperior) {
    assert limiteInferior < limiteSuperior : "lower limit must be lower";
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.limiteInferior = limiteInferior;
    this.limiteSuperior = limiteSuperior;
}

public static Dato create(String nombre, float limiteInferior, float limiteSuperior) {
    if (limiteInferior >= limiteSuperior) {
        return null;
    }
    // params are valid, let's create this thing
    return new Dato(nombre, limiteInferior, limiteSuperior);
}
```

Or you can throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, for example:

```
public Dato(String nombre, float limiteInferior, float limiteSuperior) {
    //Validar que el limite superior no sea menor o igual al inferior
    if (limiteInferior >= limiteSuperior) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range!");
    }
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.limiteInferior = limiteInferior;
    this.limiteSuperior = limiteSuperior;
}
```